# Remove & sort "using" statements in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, refactoring

Is there a way to automate the "Removal & Sorting" of "using" statements in Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the (free) "[Power Commands](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/DF3F0C30-3D37-4E06-9EF8-3BFF3508BE31)" extensions, that has a "remove&sort usings" at the project level.
Plus a "remove and sort on save" option.

See: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/e5f41ad9-4edc-4912-bca3-91147db95b99

Comment: Link to version for VS 2008: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/DF3F0C30-3D37-4E06-9EF8-3BFF3508BE31

Comment: HOLY TIME-SAVER BATMAN!  I have a multi-project solution with 1000'S of classes that are BLOATED with excess using statements....you just made my day!

Comment: Oh!  And to those reading this...the tool above works like a CHAMP!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I'm aware of is using a third party tool like [CodeRush & Refactor Pro!](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/) or [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).